# How to clear uimage from cache in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am working on my first app with the different figures, appearing on screen. Firstly it should be stars and in the next round cirles. The problem is: the new figures appear properly, but the previous ones don't disappear. I read in internet that the problem may be that they stay in cache. The suggested solution was to use `UIImage(contentsOfFile:..)` instead of `UIImage(named:..)`. I try to follow it but result is the same.

Here is my code:

```
func chooseFigure() {


    switch (countRound-1) {

    case 0 :
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("star", ofType: "png")
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)

        thisCard.image = image!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

    case 1 :
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("circle", ofType: "png")
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)

        thisCard.image = image!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

    default:
        cards[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using to delete or hide the previous state before starting the present state. Use if-else inside the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it. The problem was not in cache (thanks for the idea, Abhishek Biswas and Arun Basil Issac). All I need to do was to delete the old subviews before I load the new ones.

Here is the code:

```
    for view in layout.layoutMid.midSubView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```